# Vagrant is not syncing files

Tags: vagrant

So I've been looking around a little bit for this issue, but maybe I lack something.
I freshly generated a Vagrant VM (With VirtualBox) but the files only seem to sync 1 time when the server loads/reloads.
I only have this in my configuration file, am I missing something here?

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/stretch64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 25565, host: 25565
     config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "8192"
  end
end
```

I also tried with

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_files"
```

But that doesn't seem to change anything.
I don't have any errors on load, but the result is that when I add a file on the server, I don't see it in the project folder on my pc